# Php issues after 6th decimal

Tags: php, numbers, echo

I have serious issues with decimals.

```
$var1 = 0.0019935727215457;
$var2 = $var1 * 4 / 100;
echo $var2;
```

Output:

```
7.9742908861829E-5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var1 = 0.0019935727215457;
$var2 = $var1 * 4 / 100;
$ans = number_format($var2, "20");
echo $ans;
```

you can use something like this here i use 20 you can use digit according to your need.

Comment: this would work too, I made it work already yesterday myself but accepted your one because it's more complete, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's just scientific notation and the default behavior. Use number_format http://php.net/number_format